# Gramática de la frase «¡Apresúrense que vamos tarde!»

Tags: gramática

En un libro de frases y traducciones entre español e inglés encontré esta frase:

> ¡Apresúrense que vamos tarde!

Y dice que significa:

> Hurry, we're late!

Ayúdame a entender por qué.

**Apresúrense** entiendo es el imperativo de «apresurarse» (hurry yourself), y entiendo bien **vamos tarde** ("we're going late").  Pero ¿por qué la palabra **que**?  ¿Cómo sirve en la frase?

Answer (score 4):

Entre los múltiples usos que puede tener la partícula `que` (pronombre en oraciones interrogativas, exclamativas o relativas, conjunción coordinante, etc.) está el introducir frases subordinadas. La oración subordinada depende de la oración principal y puede funcionar como objeto directo, sujeto, adjetivo o complemento.

El `que` de

> ¡Apresúrense **que** vamos tarde!

Es una conjunción que sirve no solo para unir ambas frases, o introducir una oración subordinada, sino para expresar **causalidad** (causa-efecto) de una frente a otra. Podría quedar un poco más claro si lo cambiamos por

> ¡Dense prisa porque vamos tarde!

La oración subordinada (vamos tarde) expresa la causa de lo denotado por la oración principal (Apresúrense / Dense prisa). El `que` es la partícula nexo que une ambas frases y explica el porqué de la primera oración en base a la segunda (subordinada).

Otro ejemplo:

> No quites la tetera del fuego **que** todavía no está hirviendo.

Podrías forzarlo como si fueran dos frases enunciativas y no usar el `que`

> No quites la tetera del fuego. [la tetera] Todavía no está hirviendo.

Pero si quieres expresar **causalidad** (una cosa es consecuencia de otra; esta es la razón por la que quiero que hagas o no hagas esto o lo otro) necesitas la partícula `que` para introducir una frase subordinada (dependiente de la primera) que explique la relación, consecuencia, causa-efecto, motivo, etc.

> No quites la tetera del fuego (por)**que** todavía no está hirviendo (y quiero que hierva para prepararme un té).

Answer (score -3):

La traducción no es buena.

> Hurry, we are late

debería ser

> Apresúrense, vamos tarde

El "que" que vio tiene el mismo significado que el "that" en

> Hurry that we are late

Que sería una traducción más precisa

Comment: La palabra **que** tiene varios significados y funciones gramaticales. Generalmente es un pronombre relativo, traducible como "**that**", pero en este caso es una conjunción causal, traducible como "**because**". La traducción más precisa sería entonces _hurry, because we are late_.

Comment: This answers doesn't explain why the "que" is used in "¡Apresúrense **que** vamos tarde!". It just compares the sentence given in the example with the grammar of a different language.